# Azure authentication for management utility

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a tool, similar to Visual Studio's Cloud Explorer, that performs a limited set of management and deployment tasks inside a user's Azure subscription.

I'm thrown-off by a few things relating to authenticating against Azure and how the application represents itself to Azure.

Most of the documentation about authentication with Azure is concerned with web-applications that let users authenticate themselves against an Azure Active Directory. This is not my scenario. While me application *necessarily* authenticates users against Azure AD (as all Azure users are), my users are administrators, not "users".

I understand previously software that performed administration tasks would be assigned a Management Certificate which is separately-registered in the web-based Azure Management Portal. I understand this fine.

...however I also understand that Management Certificates are almost deprecated and are replaced with Service Principals, which itself makes more sense from a security perspective (as it enables more granular role-based security) - however the downside is that there are a lot of manual steps and hoops to jump through in order to enable the use of Service Principals with administration software - in particular you need to pre-register your application in Azure Portal.

I don't like this because it greatly increases user-friction with the software I'm writing. I want my software to behave like the Visual Studio Cloud Explorer or Azure PowerShell in that you don't need to pre-register anything: 1. just run the program on your desktop; 2. you'll get a prompt to sign-in with your Azure administrator account credentials. 3. my softwware lists the contents of your subscriptions and lets you perform your management tasks.

So far I have actually got something that does this - I perform the following steps:

1. Use `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext` to authenticate against `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` (using `AcquireTokenAsync` which presents the webview to login). I use `clientId: "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"` which is the Azure PowerShell clientId.
2. Use the token from step 1 to enumerate Tenants and Subscriptions in the user's account.
3. The user is prompted to select a tenant and then a subscription from the list downloaded in step 2.
4. Send a new authentication request to `https://login.microsoft.com/{tenantId}` (where `{tenantId}` is retrieved from step 3), again using the same `clientId`.

However I don't like impersonating Azure PowerShell - Microsoft could revoke that clientId.

...but how do I register a clientId that can be used to login in step 1 (when there's no `tenantId` or subscription context, thus no Azure AD which contains Service Principals)?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't like this because it greatly increases user-friction with the software I'm writing. I want my software to behave like the Visual Studio Cloud Explorer or Azure PowerShell in that you don't need to pre-register anything: 1. just run the program on your desktop; 2. you'll get a prompt to sign-in with your Azure administrator account credentials. 3. my softwware lists the contents of your subscriptions and lets you perform your management tasks.

Actually, the Visual Studio Cloud Explorer also register the app on the Azure AD and use the [Service Management REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) to manage the Azure subscription. And you can caputer the request using the **Fiddler** when you add account to the Cloud Explorer.

> ...but how do I register a clientId that can be used to login in step 1 (when there's no tenantId or subscription context, thus no Azure AD which contains Service Principals)?

We need to develope a [multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#related-content) which enables the users from different tenant to use the application. After that we can use the **Common** endpoint instead of the specific tenant id you register the app. Then users login-in with their account which associate with Azure subscription and get the access token for the **Service Management REST**. At last the applicaiton can manage the Azure resource with the access token. For example, we can use the REST below to list the Azure Sbuscriptions:

```
Get:https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptions
Authorization: Bearer {token}
x-ms-version: 2013-08-01
```

And more detail about the authenticating Service Management requests, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx).